# Flipping sprite by y axis when rotated past a certain point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity, and an amateur C# user. I have a submarine sprite that I would like to flip by the y-axis when rotated more than 90 degrees, and less than -90 degrees so that it won't be upside down. It's rotated by mouse movement which I'll give the code if necessary. I'm not sure why but, this doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated!

Code:(rot90 is a bool)

```
if (transform.rotation.z > 90 & transform.rotation.z >-90)
{
    rot90 = false;
}

if (transform.rotation.z < 90 & transform.rotation.z < -90) 
{
    rot90 = true;
}

if (rot90 == true)
{
    Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;
    scale.y = -22;
    transform.localScale = scale;
}

if (rot90 == false)
{
    Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;
    scale.y = 22;
    transform.localScale = scale;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`transform.rotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html) is a [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html)!

A [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) has not only 3 but **4** component `x`, `y`, `z` **and `w`**, and they all move in ranges between `-1` and `1`.

Your conditions can **never** become `true`!

---

You could use the [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) and do e.g.

```
var zAngle = transform.eulerAngles.z;
// clean out the angle to a value between -180 and +180
while(zAngle > 180) zAngle -= 360;
while(zAngle < -180) zAngle += 360;

Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;
scale.y = Mathf.Abs(zAngle) > 90 ? -22 : 22;
transform.localScale = scale;
```

in case you are using a [`SpriteRenderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer.html) component you should rather go for [`SpriteRenderer.flipY`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-flipY.html)

```
var zAngle = transform.eulerAngles.z;
// clean out the angle to a value between -180 and +180
while(zAngle > 180) zAngle -= 360;
while(zAngle < -180) zAngle += 360;

// You should of course rather cache this reference e.g. in Awake only once
// and then reuse it here
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipY = Mathf.Abs(zAngle) > 90;
```